# Not able to bind dynamic *ngSwitchCase values with [class.active]

Tags: angular, dynamic, binding, switch-statement

I need to render vertical tabs and their related values (in right side div) dynamically

I am trying to bind dynamically created `[class.active]` fields with dynamically created `*ngSwitchCase`, but no luck.
Not sure what am I missing.

Here is my code,

```
<!--Below is the vertical list that gets populated, THIS WORKS, factor list gets populated-->
<ul>
     <li [class.active]="subSectionName == 'proposals'">
     <a (click)="subSectionName = 'proposals'">Proposal Summary</a></li>
                        
     <li *ngFor="let val of factor; let i=index"
     [class.active]="factorName == 'factor'+i">
     <a (click)="factorName == 'factor'+i">{{val.factorTitle}}</a></li>
</ul>

<!--Below is the code for the right section divs data that renders 
on clicking the related tab from the vertical tabs -->

 <div [ngSwitch]="subSectionName">
   <div *ngSwitchCase="'proposals'">
      <div><h2>Proposal Summary</h2></div>  <!--THIS WORKS-->
   </div>
 </div>     

 <!--BELOW DOES NOT RENDER-->
<div *ngFor="let val of factor; let i=index" [ngSwitch]="factorName">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'factor'+i"> <div>Factor {{val.factorTitle}} </div>
</div>
```

I tried with using only index value, and also by val.id, but its not working.
I also tried looping the ngSwitchcase for factor inside subSectionName switchcase.
I am not sure if the *ngSwitchCase name is not matching with the tabs name or is it not getting bonded correctly.

Please help.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: Nop, no error, nothing happens.
When I click on Proposal Summary, corresponding div renders, but nothing happens when I click on factor titles

Comment: <a (click)="factorName == 'factor'+i">{{val.factorTitle}}</a></li> why are you comparing value here?

Comment: Oh! my God.. Thanks for pointing it out, it was a typo.. and I tried what not. Its working now. Thanks @Chellappanவ

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this is the only problem here, but you can't add two structural directives to the same element in Angular. It also appears that you have one more opening div tag than you have closing div tags, which could also cause this problem. Finally, because you can't use the `ngFor` and `ngSwitchCase` directives on the same element, you'd have to take the `ngSwitchCase` down one level in a new div and if it doesn't meet the condition then `ngFor` will have created an empty div that doesn't add any value.

Instead, try changing the bit that isn't rendering to:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let val of factor; let i=index">
   <div *ngIf="factorName === 'factor'+i">{{val.factorTitle}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

If this doesn't work, please try to re-create your issue in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so that we can see your exact use case and help further.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Kyler , I just made a typo, instead of assigning the value, I was comparing it. It is working now. I made some changes though. Will post it. And yes, I will try to create issue in stackblitz next time.

Answer (score 0):

It might help someone, hence posting my code.
Made below changes, it is working now,

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li [class.active]="subSectionName == 'proposals'">
    <a (click)="subSectionName = 'proposals'">Proposal Summary</a>
  </li>
                        
  <li *ngFor="let val of factor; let i=index"
  [class.active]="subSectionName == 'factor'+i">
    <a (click)="subSectionName = 'factor'+i">{{val.factorTitle}}</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div [ngSwitch]="subSectionName">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'proposals'">
     <div><h2>Proposal Summary</h2>
   </div>                    
                    
   <div *ngFor="let val of factor; let i=index" >
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'factor'+i"> 
          <div>Factor {{val.factorTitle}} </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```